# Is it required to include any files from gomoob:php-pushwooshto to run a PHP program to send push notifications to iPhone?

Tags: php, push-notification, require, pushwoosh, php-include

I want to send push notifications to iPhone devices by writing PHP code for it.

**gomoob:php-pushwoosh** is a PHP Library that easily work with the pushwoosh REST Web Services.

[This is the URL for gomoob:php-pushwoosh](http://gomoob.github.io/php-pushwoosh/)

As per the instructions I've installed **gomoob:php-pushwoosh** on my local machine using **Composer** at location **'/var/www/gomoob-php-pushwoosh'**

I wrote following code in a file titled `sample_1.php` which is present at location **'/var/www/gomoob-php-pushwoosh/sample_1.php'**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';


// Create a Pushwoosh client
$pushwoosh = Pushwoosh::create()
    ->setApplication('XXXX-XXX')
    ->setAuth('xxxxxxxx');

// Create a request for the '/createMessage' Web Service
$request = CreateMessageRequest::create()
    ->addNotification(Notification::create()->setContent('Hello Jean !'));

// Call the REST Web Service
$response = $pushwoosh->createMessage($request);

// Check if its ok
if($response->isOk()) {
    print 'Great, my message has been sent !';
} else {
    print 'Oups, the sent failed :-('; 
    print 'Status code : ' . $response->getStatusCode();
    print 'Status message : ' . $response->getStatusMessage();
}
?>
```

But I'm getting following error for it :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Pushwoosh' not found in /var/www/gomoob-php-pushwoosh/sample_1.php on line 9
```

At the [Link](http://gomoob.github.io/php-pushwoosh/) they have not mentioned that any file needs to be included into the code. They have only written sample code program. I've used that program as it is but getting error for it.

So can someone please help me in running this program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class you want resides in a namespace, so you need to instruct PHP to "import" it (and other classes) from there; add this to the beginning of your script:

```
    use Gomoob\Pushwoosh\Client\Pushwoosh;
    use Gomoob\Pushwoosh\Model\Request\CreateMessageRequest;
    use Gomoob\Pushwoosh\Model\Notification\Notification;

    require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```